# Adobe Photoshop error message about display driver with my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, display, adobe-photoshop

I have just installed Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.  When it came up, after lots of time and annoying spinning colored disk, I got the message "Photoshop has encountered a problem with the display driver, and has temporarily disabled enhancements which use the graphics hardware.  Check the manufacturer's website for the latest software."  I bought my computer January 2, 2011.  After reading here about display problems, I don't know where I fit in.  Since I am using Photoshop for a class, I don't think I want enhancements disabled.  Can anyone tell me which way to turn?  Is my 2011 MacBook Pro, running Yosemite 10.10.5, now considered "old"?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using the latest version of Adobe Photoshop CC 2015.

http://blogs.adobe.com/crawlspace/2011/03/keeping-photoshop-up-to-date.html

Your MacBook should be working just fine, my late 2009 iMac still runs like a champ.